# Which facebook design should you use for facebook login?

Tags: login, human-interface-guideline, facebook, social

Recently facebook changed its products design and changed to a new logo. According to their [brand resource center](https://en.facebookbrand.com/) you should use their new logo and color. But their [facebook for developers](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web/login-button/) still uses the old facebook login. I am not sure if they havent updated it or you're still supposed to use the old design.

This is my take on facebook login with the new logo & color. Which one are you supposed to use?

[image: e]

Answer (score 1):

I am not a Facebook developer but my guess is that they are taking their time deploying the new design to their different teams. If I were in your situation I would definitely use the newer guidelines.